# Do I need to uninstall and reinstall xcode once I have gotten my certificates?

Tags: iphone, xcode

Oh my god!!! Getting Xcode to work is turning out to be one of the most challenging things of my life so far!

Please answer this one question:

I downloaded the SDK before getting my certificate and I have created some practice apps following along with the iTunes University.  I thought you could do all this without a certificate, but I went to compile the examples and got the "no proper keychain" warning.  OK cool no problem.  I got the certificates now and have installed them on my computer.  But I now get a "no proper provisioning profile" error.

So my question:
Do I need to reinstall xcode and rebuild these practice apps, or is there some easy thing I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need to reinstall Xcode, it would be ridiculous if you had to do that.

I don't have much experience with code signing, here are some things you can easily check:

Did you select the correct code signing profile in your project build settings?
Project > Edit project settings > Build > search for 'code sign'. Check 'Code Signing Identity'.

If you're trying to debug on a device, check the provisioning profiles for the device in Window > Organiser